# What to do so the duplicated fields appear on the right?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want when to click on the button the duplicate field to appear on the right half of the page next to the original field.

I created this code, but when I click on the button the duplicated fields appear below the original, it should be the same as the original only to be on the right half of the page aligned with the original.

```js
    var counter = 1;

    function duplicate() {
      // Get the input fields container
      var inputContainer = document.getElementById("inputs");

      // Get the input fields to duplicate
      var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
      var input2 = document.getElementById("input2");

      // Clone the input fields
      var clonedInput1 = input1.cloneNode(true);
      var clonedInput2 = input2.cloneNode(true);

      // Generate unique IDs for the cloned input fields
      clonedInput1.id = "input1-" + counter;
      clonedInput2.id = "input2-" + counter;
      counter++;

      // Append the cloned input fields to the duplicated inputs container
      var duplicatedInputsContainer = document.getElementById("duplicatedInputs");
      duplicatedInputsContainer.appendChild(clonedInput1);
      duplicatedInputsContainer.appendChild(clonedInput2);
    }
```

```html
<div id="inputs" class="short">
    <input id="input1" class="input" placeholder=" Add label..." type="text">
    <hr class="hr1">
    <input id="input2" class="placeholder" placeholder=" Add placeholder..." type="text">
    <button class="btn btn-delete">
      <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
    </button>
    <button onclick="duplicate()" class="button1">
     <img src="https://img.icons8.com/android/24/null/plus.png"/>
    </button>
 </div>
<div id="duplicatedInputs"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A flexbox can be helpful in this scenario, by default divs have a styling of `display: block`, which means that it takes up the complete space it can get, and hence the new line.

To bring it on the right side of your webpage, you can enclose your current code in another div, and give a flexbox style to it

Sample Code:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="inputs" class="short">
        <input id="input1" class="input" placeholder=" Add label..." type="text">
        <hr class="hr1">
        <input id="input2" class="placeholder" placeholder=" Add placeholder..." type="text">
        <button class="btn btn-delete">
          <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
        </button>
        <button onclick="duplicate()" class="button1">
          <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div id="duplicatedInputs"></div>
 </div>
```

And provide the following css to the class "wrapper"

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

This will render both of your divs in a row format, and space them evenly to take up your width.